# Discord bot can't detect message author python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Discord bot will not allow me to trigger a command when a certain user sends a message.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")


@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author == "exampleuser#0000":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "success")

client.run("insert token here")
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! In order for us to help you, you need to provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [the documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Message.author), `message.author` is a [`Member` object](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.Member), not a string. Comparing a member to a string will always result in `False`.

---

Since `Member` is a subclass of [`User`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.User), you can use the [`id` attribute](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message#discord.User.id) to identify the author:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author.id == "some_id":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "success")
```

[This article](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) describes how to find a user's ID. To sum it up:

1. Enable Developer Mode under Settings -> Appearance -> Advanced
2. Right click a user and hit "copy ID"

Answer (score 1):

You could instead try

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author.id == "author ID":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "success")
```

To find the id of a person, first enable developer mode in discord (Settings, Appearance, Advanced). After that, right click on their name in discord and click Copy Id. Then, paste the ID in the author ID. Hope this helps!